# Отображение кнопки в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Как отобразить `Button` напротив строки на которую наведен курсор или же напротив строки на которую нажал пользователь? Пример на рисунке.

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При наведении никак (насколько знаю). Но можно сделать при щелчке ЛКМ по нужной строке. Вот как то так :

```
        private void richTextBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
        button1.Visible = true;

        int index = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        int line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(index);
        button1.Visible = true;
        int x = richTextBox1.Location.X - 80;
        int y = 12;

        for (int i=0; i<richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
        button1.Location = new Point(x, richTextBox1.Location.Y + line *y);
        }
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По итогу обсуждения в чате, скорее всего вам нужно не линии считать а позицию курсора в целом, вот так :

```
    private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = richTextBox1.Location.X - 80;
        button2.Location = new Point(100, Cursor.Position.Y - 150);
    }
```

Comment: Что-то не работает. Button появляется только при клике по первой строке и в том месте где его изначально поместили. И зачем button2?

Comment: @Kaya Я вас не правильно понял. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Кнопка как-то убегает. Отображается слишком далеко от начала строки и не напротив неё. http://i.imgur.com/dY6vSV0.png

Comment: @Kaya  корректируйте `y`. Поставьте меньше.  или так - `new Point(x, richTextBox1.Location.Y + line *  y);`

Comment: Мне кажется проблема не в этом http://imgur.com/KKiAb1b

Comment: @Kaya лучше покажите код

Comment: @Kaya значение `у` это значение приращения по оси `Y` с каждой новой строкой. оно умножается на номер строки и получается новая координата.

Comment: Ссылка на проект - https://yadi.sk/d/SSlhh0_n3JuXje

Comment: @Kaya `int y = 25;

            for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
            {
                button2.Location = new Point(x, richTextBox1.Location.Y + line * y);
            }`

Comment: Теперь все отлично, но если использовать ScrollBar который появляется автоматически и перетянуть страницу чуть ниже то Button опять начинает плавать.

Comment: @Kaya естественно он будет убегать со скрол баром. только про скрол бар в вашем вопросе ничего не написано.

Comment: @Kaya Используй Позицию курсора а не линии в ричбоксе. `int x = richTextBox1.Location.X - 80;
            button2.Location = new Point(100, Cursor.Position.Y-150);`

Comment: @Kaya тогда и координаты при наведении можно легко менять.

Comment: Так действительно лучше. Плохо только что позиция Button по вертикали зависит от точного положения клика курсора, т.е. Button иногда не прямо напротив строки.

Comment: @Kaya что мешает его подкоректировать ?

Comment: Я попробую. Есть еще один нюанс. Если форму развернуть на весь экран или просто растянуть по вертикали, то Button опять прыгает.

Comment: @Kaya это уже тема отдельного вопроса.

Comment: `Cursor.Location` возвращает координаты относительно _экрана_. Их нужно преобразовать в координаты относительно контрола. Для этого используйте метод `PointToClient`. Вызываеть его нужно у того контрола, в котором будет размещена кнопка. @Kaya